# creating unlimited sub domains programmatically through api

Tags: dns, subdomain, api, dns-servers, automation

**Note**

Consider each subdomain as unique application instance

**For information about application architecture visit**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272776/using-phusion-passenger-nginx-running-same-rails-app-with-multiple-instance

I am having one product going to provide to multiple clients with subdomains

```
www.client1.product.com to www.client100.product.com in server 1 
with some static ip (x.x.x.1).
```

After 100 clients server 1 reaches maximum resource load and space, so i am buying another new server putting

`www.client101.product.com to www.client200.product.com with ip (x.x.x.2)` ,

consider i am using premium dns hosting for adding more than 100 A records. Is there any way to **automate sub domain creation**, by adding corresponding server ip to the A records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will depend on your DNS hosting is done.

I personally use [Zonomi](http://zonomi.com/).  They have a [DNS API](https://zonomi.com/app/dns/dyndns.jsp).  I can issue a request like `https://zonomi.com/app/dns/dyndns.jsp?action=SET&name=mynewsubdomain.example.com&value=10.0.0.1&type=A&api_key=apikeyvaluehere` to set the IP address for a new subdomain.

Another solution would be use use Route53 from Amazon Web Services (AWS).  You can use the AWS JSON API or command line tool to modify DNS records at their Route53 DNS provider.   The documentation for doing so is: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53/change-resource-record-sets.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing, i could see they are offering up to 150 DNS records, And i couldn't understand about DNS hosting units. Can you please explain for this newbie

Comment: That is their pricing structure.  It ends up being one of the most reasonable "pay for what you use" pricing structures I have ever seen.  The more DNS records you add, and the more domains you have, and the more DNS queries your users perform, the more they charge you.  I usually use $1.24 worth of services per month.  They will tell you what you will be charged based on your current setup, so you are never surprised.  If you remove domains or records from them, your charges automatically drop accordingly.

Comment: And they offer unlimited DNS records.  Their pricing is $5/year for every 50 of them.  So if you have 500 you would be charged $4.16 each month ($50/12 months).